# TypeError in Numpy happening randomly

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

I'm having a weird issue with numpy right now on a current assignment. I'm making an ant colony AI for a class (based on the Google AI Ants Challenge), and I'm using a diffusion based approach where I essentially diffuse out a scent from food/enemy hills on each turn. I've been using numpy since each turn basically consists of doing a lot of matrix manipulations, but I just recently got a weird bug that I can't figure out.

At the beginning of each turn, I update the field associated with each scent before I run the diffusion iterations:

```
# Here I update the "potential" field (hills_f) and the
# diffusion values (hills_l) for the hills scent. Diffusion values
# (lambda values) are 1 except for on ants, where they are higher
# or lower depending on their colony.
self.hills_f *= TURN_DECAY
self.hills_l = np.ones_like(self.hills_l)

# Update the lambda matrix                                                                                                           
for r,c in ants.my_ants():
    self.hills_l[r][c] = MY_HILLS_LAMBDA

for r,c in ants.enemy_ants():
    self.hills_l[r][c] = ENEMY_HILLS_LAMBDA
```

So this code runs at the beginning of each turn (along with a similar snippet for the food scent), but on a random turn (ranges from 10-40), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "long_file_path...", line 167, in run
    bot.do_turn(ants)
  File "MyBot.py", line 137, in do_turn
    self.hills_l[r][c] = ENEMY_HILLS_LAMBDA
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

It looks like it randomly turns `self.hills_l` into a scalar between the two for-loops, which doesn't make any sense to me. It's also weird that there's similar code for the food scent, which doesn't crash ever, and that this problem shows up so non-deterministically.

I can post more code if necessary, but I think everything should be there, especially since the problem seems to occur between the for loops.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, is it possible that it's `hills_l[r]` that's a scalar?

Comment: Following up on @JeffTratner comment; why don't you address the array as follows: `self.hills_l[r,c]`? Do you still get the same issue in this case? If not, you could consider posting more code to ease debugging.

Comment: @fgb I didn't realize you could index using self.hills_l[r,c], thanks for the tip! I figured out my bug, it was very annoying, but it makes sense now that I know you can index that way. The problem was that ants.enemy_hills returns two values: a 2-tuple (location) and an int (the owner of that hill). That meant that my code essentially looked like `self.hills_l[loc][owner]` , so I was trying to access the 3rd axis of a 2-d array.

Comment: Consider adding an answer to your own question since you've solved this one.